# How can I evaluate this sum of product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$$

I have no idea . Thank you.

Comment: If you call $a_n=\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-1}{\sqrt{k}}$, so that the series is $\sum\prod a_n$, so that this is equal to $a_0(1+a_1(1+a_2(1+\dots)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that the sum is equal to $1$.

Let us define the sequence $\{a_n\}$ by setting $a_0=1$, and for $n\geq1$, 
$$a_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-1}{\sqrt{k}}.$$
Also, let $b_n=\sqrt{n}a_{n-1}$ for $n\geq1$.
Clearly we have
$$b_n-b_{n+1}=\left(\sqrt{n}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-1} -\sqrt{n+1}\right)a_n=a_n$$
Thus
$$b_1-b_{m+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_n\tag{1}$$
This proves that the series of positive terms $\sum a_m$ has bounded partial sums, and consequently it must converge, and if $s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ then the sequence $\{b_m\}$ is convergent, and $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}b_{m+1}=b_1-s$.

Now, if $b_1-s\ne 0$ then we conclude from the limit above that $a_m\sim\frac{b_1-s}{\sqrt{m+1}}$, and this is absurd since the series $\sum a_m$  is convergent. Thus, we must have $b_1-s=0$ or equivalently $s=b_1=1$.